# Using ACRA with BugSense doesn't work on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, error-reporting, acra, bugsense

I'm developing an app for Android and I've recently started using ACRA for easy error reporting.
I'm using BugSense as a backend to view and inspect the errors.
I've been testing this on a Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.3 and it worked fine,
but when I tried it on a Galaxy S1 with Android 4.1.2 CyanogenMod and on a Galaxy S3 with Android 4.*, it stopped working for some reason.
Here is my ACRA reporting code:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "http://www.bugsense.com/api/acra?api_key=PLACEHOLDER", 
    formKey = "",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG,
    resDialogTitle = R.string.crash_title,
    resDialogText = R.string.crash_text,
    resDialogOkToast = R.string.crash_confirmation_text
    )
public class PLACEHOLDER extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //triggers the initialization of ACRA for error reporting
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

When the app crashes, a dialog comes up, I press OK, a thank you message appears but I see nothing on BugSense.
This seems to be more a problem with BugSense than with ACRA but I just can't figure out what is wrong.
When I tell ACRA to send an email instead of reporting to bugsense, it works fine.

Thanks, Tal

Comment: This is a problem with HTTPClient https://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=141

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience there is some issue with a variable being something like 'Wed' instead of 'Wednesday' I reported the issue a while ago but nothing was done, and there is nothing to be done from our side as far as i know. So possibly just try using the bugsense jar etc. it's really easy to setup, and run. Otherwise try get onto Crashlytics. Extremely easy and awesome crash reporting.